# Socket.io rooms difference between broadcast.to and sockets.in

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Socket.io's readme contains the following example:

```js
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
      socket.join('justin bieber fans');
      socket.broadcast.to('justin bieber fans').emit('new fan');
      io.sockets.in('rammstein fans').emit('new non-fan');
    });
```

What's the difference between `socket.broadcast.to()` and `io.sockets.in()`?

Comment: upvote for the example data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52646273/client-functions-not-working-when-a-react-component-is-render/52650559#52650559

Answer (score 136, accepted):

`socket.broadcast.to` broadcasts to all sockets in the given room, *except* to the socket on which it was called while `io.sockets.in` broadcasts to all sockets in the given room.

Comment: in what way a channel is different than a room?

Comment: in none. Different name for same thing.

Comment: socket.io uses the term room instead of channel. rooms/channels are not to be confused with namespaces in socket.io though.

I updated my answer to use the correct term.

Answer (score 48):

**Update 2019**: socket.io is a special module which uses websockets and then fallsback to http request polling. For just websockets: for the client use native websockets and for node.js use ws or this library.

### Simple example

The syntax is confusing in socketio. Also, every socket is automatically connected to their own room with the id `socket.id` (this is how private chat works in socketio, they use rooms).

**Send to the sender and noone else**

```
socket.emit('hello', msg);
```

**Send to everyone *including* the sender(if the sender is in the room) in *the room "my room"***

```
io.to('my room').emit('hello', msg);
```

**Send to everyone *except* the sender(if the sender is in the room) in *the room "my room"***

```
socket.broadcast.to('my room').emit('hello', msg);
```

**Send to everyone in *every room*, *including* the sender**

```
io.emit('hello', msg); // short version

io.sockets.emit('hello', msg);
```

**Send to specific socket only (private chat)**

```
socket.broadcast.to(otherSocket.id).emit('hello', msg);
```

Comment: How to find **otherSocket.id**. where to set it?

Comment: @ImanMarashi All you need to do is get the other socket object and then access it's id property. 
`otherSocket.on('connect',()=> { console.log(otherSocket.id); });`

Comment: Awesome ! io.to('my room').emit('hello', msg); its help me :)

Comment: @ImanMarashi you save the otherSocket.id in an array or object outside. And access it later from whichever socket in being called.

Comment: Great answer! How would we do these with redis as the adapter?

Comment: Also, what's the correct setup for socket.io so that we can reuse it in other files?

Answer (score 43):

Node.js was something I was really interested forawhile and I used it in one of my project to make a multiplayer game.

`io.sockets.in().emit()` and `socket.broadcast.to().emit()` are the main two emit methods we use in Socket.io's Rooms (https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms) Rooms allow simple partitioning of the connected clients. This allows events to be emitted with to subsets of the connected client list, and gives a simple method of managing them.

They allow us to manage the subsets of the connected client list(which we call rooms) and have the similiar functionalities like the main socket.io functions `io.sockets.emit()` and `socket.broadcast.emit()`.

Anyway I'll try to give the example codes with the comments to explain. See if it helps;

**Socket.io Rooms**

i) io.sockets.in().emit();

```
/* Send message to the room1. It broadcasts the data to all 
   the socket clients which are connected to the room1 */

io.sockets.in('room1').emit('function', {foo:bar});
```

ii) socket.broadcast.to().emit();

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('function', function(data){

        /* Broadcast to room1 except the sender. In other word, 
            It broadcast all the socket clients which are connected 
            to the room1 except the sender */
        socket.broadcast.to('room1').emit('function', {foo:bar});

    }
}
```

**Socket.io**

i) io.sockets.emit();

```
/* Send message to all. It broadcasts the data to all 
   the socket clients which are connected to the server; */

io.sockets.emit('function', {foo:bar});
```

ii) socket.broadcast.emit();

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('function', function(data){

        // Broadcast to all the socket clients except the sender
        socket.broadcast.emit('function', {foo:bar}); 

    }
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 15):

```
io.on('connect', onConnect);

function onConnect(socket){

  // sending to the client
  socket.emit('hello', 'can you hear me?', 1, 2, 'abc');

  // sending to all clients except sender
  socket.broadcast.emit('broadcast', 'hello friends!');

  // sending to all clients in 'game' room except sender
  socket.to('game').emit('nice game', "let's play a game");

  // sending to all clients in 'game1' and/or in 'game2' room, except sender
  socket.to('game1').to('game2').emit('nice game', "let's play a game (too)");

  // sending to all clients in 'game' room, including sender
  io.in('game').emit('big-announcement', 'the game will start soon');

  // sending to all clients in namespace 'myNamespace', including sender
  io.of('myNamespace').emit('bigger-announcement', 'the tournament will start soon');

  // sending to a specific room in a specific namespace, including sender
  io.of('myNamespace').to('room').emit('event', 'message');

  // sending to individual socketid (private message)
  io.to(`${socketId}`).emit('hey', 'I just met you');

  // WARNING: `socket.to(socket.id).emit()` will NOT work, as it will send to everyone in the room
  // named `socket.id` but the sender. Please use the classic `socket.emit()` instead.

  // sending with acknowledgement
  socket.emit('question', 'do you think so?', function (answer) {});

  // sending without compression
  socket.compress(false).emit('uncompressed', "that's rough");

  // sending a message that might be dropped if the client is not ready to receive messages
  socket.volatile.emit('maybe', 'do you really need it?');

  // specifying whether the data to send has binary data
  socket.binary(false).emit('what', 'I have no binaries!');

  // sending to all clients on this node (when using multiple nodes)
  io.local.emit('hi', 'my lovely babies');

  // sending to all connected clients
  io.emit('an event sent to all connected clients');

};
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation to accompany the code? Generally just providing code is frowned upon. However, I can see that your code is well-commented :)

Answer (score 1):

In Socket.IO 1.0, .to() and .in() are the same. And others in the room will receive the message. The client sends it won't receive the message.

Check out source code (v1.0.6):

https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/a40068b5f328fe50a2cd1e54c681be792d89a595/lib/socket.js#L173

Comment: Since `.to()` and `,in` are the same, then what would happen when I create a room with the exact same name as some socket's id. What would `socket.broadcast.to(socketid)` for example do then?