# socket.io create dynamic room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have been googling for 2 days on my problem to dynamically create rooms on socket.io using nodeJs. When I create a room to the server, I make it like this:

```
socket.on('follow_me', function (user_id) { //I use the user_id of the user to create room

    socket.join(user_id);

    console.log(server.sockets.manager.rooms);
});
```

If next, I want to send a message to all persons connected in the by using

```
socket.join(user_id);
```

when i use :

```
socket.on('message', function (data) {

    socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('recieve',data.message); //emit to 'room' except this socket

});
```

The other users in this room do not receive the message; but if I use:

```
socket.join(user_id);`,when i use :

    socket.on('message', function (data) {

    socket.broadcast.emit('recieve',data.message);

});
```

all user receive the message. Why room do not work for me? I think the code is good!

Tank's

Comment: See [Socket.io rooms difference between broadcast.to and sockets.in][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873607/socket-io-rooms-difference-between-broadcast-to-and-sockets-in

Comment: The code looks good, maybe, check **data.room**.

Comment: Try this, it used EJS and rooms creation dynamically and save save rooms on servers as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72763264/11888809

Answer (score 1):

```
socket.on('message', function (data) {
        /*considering data.room is the correct room name you want to send message to */
        io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('recieve', data.message) //will send event to everybody in the room while 
        socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('recieve', data.message) //will broadcast to all sockets in the given room, except to the socket which called it
        /* Also socket.broadcast.emit will send to every connected socket except to socket which called it */
    });
```

I guess what you need is  `io.sockets.in`

Comment: Tank's for this answer.My problem was an error of me to my side.the io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('recieve', data.message) help to discover the bug in my code and now i continuous to use socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('recieve', data.message) without any problem.The code of socket.io was good.tank's to all