# Dynamic rooms in Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm new in node.js and socket.io. I didn't understand how to work with rooms. I'm creating something like a Private Messages. Each pair of users have their unique room.

From documentation:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join('some room');
});
```

But I need to create a room from client side. Because it's dynamic. How?

I met some examples https://gist.github.com/crtr0/2896891

**server.js**

```
io = socketio.listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('room', function(room) {
        socket.join(room);
    });
});

room = "abc123";
io.sockets.in(room).emit('message', 'what is going on, party people?');
```

This line drives me crazy. It seems to me stupid. Because server never know which room to use. Server just can handle multiple rooms.

```
room = "abc123";
```

Please, help or explain.

Answer (score 14):

In you above code you have fixed room to abc123 , that you need to make it dynamic for all connected clients . You can provide room create option to user also you can provide logic to change/rename/leave/join room from client. Basically in your client and server you can apply below logical changes.

Client logic to update or change room :

```
socket.emit('switchRoom', newRoom);

socket.on('updaterooms', function(rooms, current_room) {
  // Update new room logic

}
```

Server Logic to handle room change :

```
socket.on('switchRoom', function(newroom){
        // leave the current room (stored in session)
        socket.leave(socket.room);
        // join new room, received as function parameter
        socket.join(newroom);
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected to '+ newroom);
        // sent message to OLD room
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username+' has left this room');
        // update socket session room title
        socket.room = newroom;
        socket.broadcast.to(newroom).emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username+' has joined this room');
        socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, newroom);
    });
```

Refer Below Example :

[Socket.io Multi-room Example](http://psitsmike.com/2011/10/node-js-and-socket-io-multiroom-chat-tutorial/)

[Rooms and Namespace in socket.io](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved my problem! If you use rooms within namespaces, don't forget write `.of('your_namespace')`

Comment: hi am having the same problem can you explain more how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I created my own way of creating rooms from client side dynamically and it worked.

You can found video tutorial on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5OKKudZTeY&list=PLZdwvOOinjFbzhZutEK9HvC56nicFXSpZ&index=8&t=0s

I used EJS for rendering.

Index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);
const path = require('path');
const roomsList = [];
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    //res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    res.render(path.join(__dirname,'/','index.html'),{rooms: roomsList});
});


app.get('/room/', (req, res) => {
    var name = req.query.name;
    res.render(path.join(__dirname,'/','rooms.html'),{rooms: name});
});
app.get('/addRoom/', (req, res) => {
    var name = req.query.name;
    roomsList.push(name);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(roomList));
    res.send(200);
});
const adminNameSpace = io.of('/admin');
adminNameSpace.on('connect', (socket) => {
    //console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('join', (data)=>{
        socket.join(data.room);
        adminNameSpace.in(data.room).emit('chat message', `New Person joined the ${data.room} room `);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
      });
    socket.on('chat message', (data) => {
    console.log('message: ' + data.msg);
    adminNameSpace.in(data.room).emit('chat message', data.msg);
    });

    socket.on('send msg to all', (data) => {
        console.log('message: ' + data.msg);
        adminNameSpace.emit('chat message', data.msg);
        });
  });
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Select your room!</p>

    <p>Create Rooms</p>
    <input id='input-room-name' />
    <button onclick="createRoom()">Create Room</button><br/>
    <script>
      const rooms = '<%= rooms %>';
      const roomList = rooms.split(',');
      function createRoom()
      {
        var name = document.getElementById('input-room-name').value;
        document.body.innerHTML+= `<a href="/room?name=${name}">${name}</a><br /><br />`;
        httpGet(name);
      }
      function httpGet(name)
      {
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open("GET", `/addRoom?name=${name}`,false);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        return xmlHttp.responseText;
      }
      for (const name of roomList)
      {
        if(name!='')
          document.body.innerHTML += `<a href="/room?name=${name}">${name}</a><br /><br />`;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

rooms.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; padding-bottom: 3rem; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

      #form { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); padding: 0.25rem; position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; display: flex; height: 3rem; box-sizing: border-box; backdrop-filter: blur(10px); }
      #input { border: none; padding: 0 1rem; flex-grow: 1; border-radius: 2rem; margin: 0.25rem; }
      #input:focus { outline: none; }
      #form > button { background: #333; border: none; padding: 0 1rem; margin: 0.25rem; border-radius: 3px; outline: none; color: #fff; }

      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages > li { padding: 0.5rem 1rem; }
      #messages > li:nth-child(odd) { background: #efefef; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= rooms %></h1>
    <button onclick="sendMSGToAll()">Send Message to all</button>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="form" action="">
      <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
    var socket = io('/admin');
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
  var input = document.getElementById('input');

  const room = '<%= rooms %>';
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (input.value) {
      socket.emit('chat message', {msg: input.value, room});
      input.value = '';
    }
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.textContent = msg;
    messages.appendChild(item);
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  });

  socket.on('connect', () => {
    socket.emit('join', {room: room});
  })

  function sendMSGToAll()
  {
    socket.emit('send msg to all', {msg: input.value, room});
  }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```