# How to create dynamic socket rooms using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to implement multiple chat using socket.io can, iwas able to implement one to one chat using one socket.room but i want to create multiple socket rooms to chat with multiple people parallel

below is the example i got in git but i was not able to understand that how it will work for multiple chat can any one explain 

 **Server side**

```
io = socketio.listen(server);

// handle incoming connections from clients
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
// once a client has connected, we expect to get a ping from them 
saying what room they want to join
socket.on('room', function(room) {
    socket.join(room);
});
});

// now, it's easy to send a message to just the clients in a given 
room
room = "abc123";
io.sockets.in(room).emit('message', 'what is going on, party 
people?');

 // this message will NOT go to the client defined above
 io.sockets.in('foobar').emit('message', 'anyone in this room yet?');
```

**Client side**

```
  // set-up a connection between the client and the server
 var socket = io.connect();

 // let's assume that the client page, once rendered, knows what room 
 it wants to join
 var room = "abc123";

 socket.on('connect', function() {
 // Connected, let's sign-up for to receive messages for this room
 socket.emit('room', room);
  });

 socket.on('message', function(data) {
  console.log('Incoming message:', data);
 });
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72763264/11888809

Answer (score -1):

Imagine a user with multiple Chat Room to choose. When he click on a specific room he will get the information of it : in this example ChatRoom1. 
The client socket (belonging to the user who has click on this room) has first to join this room
 → so that's why we have :

```
socket.emit(room, ChatRoom1)
```

// on the other part the server side will add the socket id of this client to this room :

```
socket.on('room', function(room) {
    socket.join(room);
});
```

Now if you want to emit a message to all socket belonging to a specific room you use this command on the server part:

```
 io.sockets.in(ChatRoom1).emit('message', 'what is going on, party 
people?');
```

→ in fact this command just send a message to all socket who is belonging to ChatRoom1

→ Basically a Room is just an array of socketId

SO now on the client side you have this :

```
 socket.on('message', function(data) {
  console.log('Incoming message:', data);
 });
```

this is just a listener, and you will get in console log : 
Incoming message: what is going on, party people?

As you soon you enter in a chatRoom your socket join a room and will listen for each event until you ask the socket to leave the room

So now you can imagine that in your message you have your Id , Your Room ID and your content, when you send it the server will know where to send it.

Example: 
message: {
content: 'blabla',
user: me,
date: now, 
RoomId: ChatRoom1
}

On the client side each time a user send a message:
socket.emit('sendMessage', message)

On the server side:

```
socket.on('sendMessage', function(message){
io.sockets.in(message.RoomId).emit('message', message);
})
```

Comment: Hi need lil bit more info could you please reply

Comment: Can you please details a little bit more what you don't understand, thanks

Comment: consiter X and Y and Z and D are 4 users, all are online ... No tell me how X able to chat Y, Z, D parallely.. Like facebook

Comment: I edit my answer sorry for the delay. After you can find plenty of tutorial on the web.