# Create chatrooms dynamically in socket.io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, wavesurfer.js

I'm developing a chat app and i have some trouble with socket.io.

Stuff works great and quick. But as soon as more people are logged in - everyone see's all the messages and rendering gets messy.

I'm sending a unique ID with each message, which i would love to create rooms with where people can chat with each other (1 on 1)

THis happens first:

```
  const socketMessage = {
    type: type,
    body: body,
    author: author,
    date: Date.now(),
    id: chatId
  };

    const io = require('socket.io-client');
    const socket = io(process.env.REACT_APP_WS_URL);
    socket.emit('message-sent', socketMessage);
```

THis goes to the server where this happens:

```
  socket.on('message-sent', data => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('new-chat-message', data);
  });
```

WHich then goes into a custom hook and adds to the messages-array.

```
export default function useGetChatMessages(_id) {
  const [chatMessages, setChatMessages] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const io = require('socket.io-client');
    const socket = io(process.env.REACT_APP_WS_URL);
    socket.emit('send-chat-id', _id);
    socket.on('chat-messages', data => {
      setChatMessages(data.messages);
    });
    socket.on('new-chat-message', message => {
      setChatMessages(messages => [...messages, message]);
      notification.play();
    });
  }, [_id]);

  return chatMessages;
}
```

I know the broadcast part is wrong on my server but i have tried lots of things:

Sending the chatId with the message and then do `socket.join(chatId)` at several stages. 
Then socket.to(chatId).emit(...) and so on. 
But i can not get it right.

Can someone help?

Thanks a lot in advance!! :-)

Comment: Did you tried this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/72763264/11888809
This works as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you could use the socket io feature called namespaces.

Look an pretty simple example:

In the client side you would do something like this:

```
const socket = io.connect(socket_url, { query: "chatRoomId=123&userId=983912" });
```

And in the server side something like this:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  const chatRoomId = socket.handshake.query['chatRoomId'];      
  const userId  = socket.handshake.query['userId'];

  const user = find(userId) // Pretend :)

  socket.join(chatRoomId);

  socket.on('new_message', (id, msg) => {
    io.to(chatRoomId).emit(`${user.name} says ${msg}`);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    socket.leave(chatRoomId)
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });

});
```

Comment: hey felipe. that is smart. i solved it now with rooms generated by ID :-)

Comment: my solution only works in local development. i might turn to this for production :-) thanks a lot!