# Socket.IO - how to emit event to everybody in the room, including sender?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, dom-events, socket.io-redis

In my Socket.Io / Node.Js / Express app - before I added chat room – I used to emit events like this for everyone (including the sender):

```
io.emit('chat message', msg);
```

Now I added rooms and try to do the same thing using

```
socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('chat message', msg);
```

or

```
socket.to(socket.room).emit('chat message', msg);
```

but both only send the message to receivers, but **not** to the sender.

What should I do so that this message also goes to the sender, who's in the chat room as well?

Comment: maybe just adding another socket.emit() will do

Answer (score 9):

Found an answer in this question:
[Socket.io Won't Emit messages to rooms on discconect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144517/socket-io-wont-emit-messages-to-rooms-on-discconect)

simply use

```
io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('chat message', msg);
```

Comment: what is "io.sockets" is not available, and only "socket" is

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer on one of [Socket.IO GitHub issues](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1183#issuecomment-48348848).

```
socket.nsp.to(room).emit(event);
```