# socket.io: why doesn't this broadcast statement work?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, broadcast

I'm trying to use broadcast statement to send messages to specific user.
However, when I'm starting with self-sending messages using the following statement, it doesn't work. The client side cannot receive the message. So what's wrong with this statement?

```js
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('message', function(msg) {
    socket.broadcast.to(socket.id).emit('message', msg);
  });
});
```

(purpose of this code: the client side send a piece of message named 'message', the server receive the message and send back to the same client)

Comment: If you're sending back to a single socket connection, why not just use `socket.send`?

Comment: So how can I send to a client with specific id using socket.send?

Answer (score 0):

`socket.broadcast.to` broadcasts to all sockets in the given room, except to the socket on which it was called while `io.sockets.in` broadcasts to all sockets in the given room. (cited from Daniel Baulig's answer to another question:)
[Socket.io rooms difference between broadcast.to and sockets.in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873607/socket-io-rooms-difference-between-broadcast-to-and-sockets-in)