# Socket.io socket.broadcast.to not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, socket.io

I have in  my `Express` server

```
userbase = {'Fitz': '84Iw3MNEIMaed0GoAAAD'}; //Exapmle user to receive message and associated socket id



//Sending message to Example user
    socket.on('send_msg',function(data_from_client){



       //Testing  for receivers socketId


     console.log(userbase[data_from_client.to_user]);//This returns the socket id for Fitz in userbase successfully i.e 84Iw3MNEIMaed0GoAAAD



      socket.broadcast.to(userbase[data_from_client.to_user]).emit('get_msg',{msg:data_server.msg});
    });
```

Surprise surprise when I setup a handler for this event on my cliens side for `'get_msg'` i get nothing.

```
.factory('SocketFctry',function(){
  var socket = io('http://localhost:3002')

  return socket;
})



.controller('ChatCtrl', function($scope,SocketFctry) {

 SocketFctry.on('get_msg',function(received_message){
   console.log(received_message);
   $scope.$apply();

 })


});
```

My other client side handlers are working fine.

```
 SocketFctry.on('new_user', function(users,my_id){
    console.log(users);
    $scope.online_users = users;
    $scope.$apply();
  })
```

My version of socket.io is 1.3.7 .Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5):

`socket.broadcast().to()` send a message to all users that match the `to()` arguments EXCEPT the user who's `socket` it is.  So, `socket.broadcast.to(socket.id)` will never send to the actual `socket` user.  In fact, by default, it won't send to anyone.

Direct from the socket.io doc:

> To broadcast, simply add a broadcast flag to emit and send method
>   calls. Broadcasting means sending a message to everyone else except
>   for the socket that starts it.

If you want to send to only a single socket, then just use:

```
socket.emit(...)
```

If you want to broadcast to a socket.id-type room and you want to include the user who's room it is, then use:

```
io.to('some room').emit('some event'):
```

So, you can change this:

```
socket.broadcast.to(userbase[data_from_client.to_user]).emit('get_msg',{msg:data_server.msg});
```

to this:

```
io.to(userbase[data_from_client.to_user]).emit('get_msg',{msg:data_server.msg});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have users join a namespace on connection?

```
socket.join(userbase[data_from_client.to_user]); //'84Iw3MNEIMaed0GoAAAD'
```

You can try:

```
socket.in(userbase[data_from_client.to_user]).emit('get_msg', {msg:data_server.msg});
```

Comment: I unsderstand each connected client is automatically added to the room with his socket#id...your solution to use `socket.in(socket.id)` worked for me, but I'm still stumped that `socket.broadcast.to(socket.id)` doesn't work. I really would like to understand why before accepting the answer.Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873607/socket-io-rooms-difference-between-broadcast-to-and-sockets-in#answer-6877212