# How to emit data to specific socket id in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using socket.io for building the real-time dashboard,

I want to send data to each connection as separate,

How to achieve this functionality in node.js using socket.io?

```
io.emit('someEvent', {data: 'data'});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058226/send-response-to-all-clients-except-sender

Comment: [Sending to a single socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550590/socket-io-socket-broadcast-to-not-working/39566080#39566080)

Comment: thanks, guys. found this method " io.sockets.connected[socket.id].emit"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the following method to emit to particular socket.id

```
io.sockets.connected[socket.id].emit('even', {
        data: `successfully fetched dat for user ${reqUser.user.userName}.`
});
```