# Send message to other rooms in Socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, server, socket.io, client

I Know how to send message to all the clients in the same room. I am using below code to send message to clients in the same room (server side).

```
io.to(Array.from(socket.rooms)[1]).emit("send message","We are in Same room")
//Array.from(socket.rooms)[1] -> getting room number from the map
```

But now I want to send message to **All the clients who are not in current room.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Socket.io rooms difference between broadcast.to and sockets.in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873607/socket-io-rooms-difference-between-broadcast-to-and-sockets-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the array with socket IDs from specific room and using that array to exclude from all connected sockets:

```js
const socketsFromRoom = Array.from(await io.in("my_room").allSockets());

Array.from(await io.allSockets())
  .filter((socketId) => !socketsFromRoom.includes(socketId))
  .forEach((socketId) => {
    io.sockets.sockets.get(socketId).emit("send_message");
  });
```